# 'unsigned variable: value' C++

Tags: c++, c++11, boolean, unsigned

I am dealing with Ternary Search Tree and I encountered a different thing in ternary search tree node structure:

```
struct Node {
    char data;

    // True if this character is last character of one of the words
    unsigned isEndOfString: 1;

    struct Node *left, *eq, *right;
};
```

It is compliled with both **C++11** and older versions. I wonder what this `unsigned isEndOfString: 1` means? How it is different from `bool isEndOfString = true` ? What type this statement refers actually and when it is convenient to use such syntax?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/bit_field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a [bit field](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/bit_field) of size 1. So `isEndOfString` is a single bit whose value is either 0 or 1.

Basically it allows you here to store a boolean flag in a single bit, minimizing the memory footprint of `Node`.

Note that bitfields are inherited from C.

Comment: Thanks! Can you tell me also the `unsigned` by default is `unsigned char` or `unsigned int`?

Comment: `unsigned` is `unsigned int` by default in standard C++